# Where does parity look when trying to import geth keystore files

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, keystore

I'm in the directory for parity keystore files, namely, **~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/keys/**
and I've run:

> parity --import-geth-keys

But I get an error saying:

> **Failed to find geth keys folder**

I've placed my Geth keystore file in this folder

Answer (score 0):

try this

> parity account import [Geth Keystore Folder Path]